# Pulling a remote repo that has same branch name as local?

Tags: git

So if I have a local branch called `animal` and then someone else
publishes a remote branch in GitHub that has the same name `animal`. What happens if I try to:

```
pull --rebase origin master
```

Will it overwrite it?

Comment: If you are dealing with `master`, nothing touches your branch. Maybe you mean to ask something else?

Comment: Why not make a new branch and have a try?

Comment: @ElpieKay I tried it. remote animal branch didn't overwrite local animal branch. so nothing happend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you'd just be rebasing your local `animal` from `origin master`.
you will only have trouble when trying to push your `animal` to the same `origin` (branch already exists).

Comment: Does it mean that I always have to be aware of remote branch names because if I don't pay attention then the remote branch animal which has different files than the local one will not be copied to my local repository?

Comment: remote branch will be downloaded if you `git fetch` it, but it won't be automatically associated to your local branch with the same name if you already created one, so no worries.
if someone already pushed a branch `animal` and you have a local `animal` you just need to rename your local branch before you can push it to the same origin, but that's an easy and safe operation: `git branch --move animal animal2` and then you can push it.

Answer (score 2):

The best idea would be rename your `animal` branch:

```
git branch --move animal my_animal
```

Of course you can also pull remote branch to local one with changed name:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b other_animal origin/animal
```